# Back button not working when Interstitial ad not available

Tags: java, android

I have placed an interstitial with click on back button in my Web View app. However , back button doesn't work when ad is not available. However, it seems to work fine after an interstitial ad has been loaded once. I am not a professional developer. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    
            //admobinterstital
            MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                }
            });
            InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", new AdRequest.Builder().build(), new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                public void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    InterstitialAd unused = MainActivity2.this.mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    Log.i("TAG", "onAdLoaded");
                }
    
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    Log.i("TAG", loadAdError.getMessage());
                    InterstitialAd unused = MainActivity2.this.mInterstitialAd = null;
                }
            });


            webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    
    
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    
            });
    
            //WEB VIEW SETTINGS
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    
    
    //LIST VIEW
    
            int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("story_key", 0);
   
            //FOR MORE URL
        }
    
     
    
        // ENABLE BACK PRESS
    
    
        public void onBackPressed() {
            InterstitialAd interstitialAd = this.mInterstitialAd;
            if (interstitialAd != null) {
                interstitialAd.show(this);
                
                if (this.webView.canGoBack()) {
                    this.webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```